# Dapper Order By Parameters

Tags: parameters, sql-order-by, dapper

This is a follow-up to this question:

[Dapper Order By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344340/dapper-order-by)

Since parameterization doesn't work in the order by clause with Dapper, what is the recommended method of keeping bobby tables at bay?  Does Dapper provide some way to clean these parameters, or is there a recommended regex, etc.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651582/sanitize-table-column-name-in-dynamic-sql-in-net-prevent-sql-injection-attack

Answer (score 6):

If you mean "ascending vs descending" - pass it in as a boolean or enum value, and append to the tsql accordingly. If you mean "which column" then usually, no matter what mechanics you use to get there, you will end up at some point with a string that is (or should be) a column name. So: just white-list this against a list of the expected column names : job done. Actually, it also wouldn't be uncommon to remap it at the same time - so the string coming in might be "name", but the column could be "Customer_Name" - fine: the lookup can double-up as the whitelist.

Note : all of this is largely unrelated to what tools you are using to get at the actual data, and would work equally on any tooling.